# How to store the data generated by an event in X11?

Tags: c, x11

I am working on an event-driven project that draws shape on an x-window. Whenever I click a mouse on the screen, new values of x and y are generated. My question is: how can I store the different values of x and y in the code below assuming each time you click a mouse, new values of x and y are generated.

```
int x, y;
x = report.xbutton.x;
y = report.xbutton.y;

if (report.xbutton.button == Button1) {
    XFillArc(display_ptr, win, gc_red, 
             x - win_height/80, y - win_height/80,
             win_height/60, win_height/60, 0, 360*64);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just add the values to a dynamically allocated list of values?  You'd probably need a structure with elements x and y, and you'd have a function to manage a list of these values?

Comment: please do you mind showing me what the function will look like because am lost

Answer (score 0):

One version of the code might be:

```
typedef struct Position
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Position;

typedef struct PosnList
{
    size_t     num_pts;
    size_t     max_pts;
    Position  *points;
} PosnList;

void add_point(int x, int y, PosnList *p)
{
    if (p->num_pts >= p->max_pts)
    {
        size_t new_num = (p->max_pts + 2) * 2;
        Position *new_pts = realloc(p->points, new_num * sizeof(Position));
        if (new_pts == 0)
            ...handle out of memory error...
        p->max_pts = new_num;
        p->points  = new_pts;
    }
    p->points[p->num_pts++] = (Position){ x, y };
}

void zap_posnlist(PosnList *p)
{
     free(p->points);
     p->num_pts = 0;
     p->max_pts = 0;
     p->points  = 0;
}
```

Then your code would do:

```
int x, y;
x = report.xbutton.x;
y = report.xbutton.y;

if (report.xbutton.button == Button1) {
    XFillArc(display_ptr, win, gc_red, 
             x - win_height/80, y - win_height/80,
             win_height/60, win_height/60, 0, 360*64);
    add_point(x, y, &positions);
}
```

where somewhere you have a variable:

```
PosnList positions = { 0, 0, 0 };
```

Note that the `add_point()` function uses `realloc()` to do both the initial memory allocation and incremental memory allocations.  The code uses a C99 compound literal to assign the values `x` and `y` to the next `Position` in the array.  If you don't have C99, you'll need to do two separate assignments.

The `zap_posnlist()` function releases a previously initialized `PosnList`.  You might still need a formal initializer function — unless you're happy to use the `PosnList xxx = { 0, 0, 0 };` notation everywhere.

This code has now been sanitized by GCC; the original edition was not and there were bugs in it — bugs that generated compiler errors.

---

Tested code — note that `"stderr.h"` is not a standard header but is the error reporting code I habitually use.  It provides the `err_error()` and `err_setarg0()` functions.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stderr.h"

typedef struct Position
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Position;

typedef struct PosnList
{
    size_t     num_pts;
    size_t     max_pts;
    Position  *points;
} PosnList;

extern void add_point(int x, int y, PosnList *p);
extern void zap_posnlist(PosnList *p);

void add_point(int x, int y, PosnList *p)
{
    if (p->num_pts >= p->max_pts)
    {
        size_t new_num = (p->max_pts + 2) * 2;
        Position *new_pts = realloc(p->points, new_num * sizeof(Position));
        if (new_pts == 0)
            err_error("Out of memory (%s:%d - %zu bytes)\n",
                       __FILE__, __LINE__, new_num * sizeof(Position));
        p->max_pts = new_num;
        p->points  = new_pts;
    }
    p->points[p->num_pts++] = (Position){ x, y };
}

void zap_posnlist(PosnList *p)
{
    free(p->points);
    p->num_pts = 0;
    p->max_pts = 0;
    p->points  = 0;
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    PosnList positions = { 0, 0, 0 };

    err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    if (argc > 1)
        srand(atoi(argv[1]));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 37; i++)
        add_point(rand(), rand(), &positions);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < positions.num_pts; i++)
        printf("%2zu: (%5d, %5d)\n", i, positions.points[i].x, positions.points[i].y);

    zap_posnlist(&positions);
    return(0);
}
```

---

*Contact me (see my profile) if you want source for `stderr.h` and `stderr.c`.*

Comment: thanks for the help so far. i tried the code and it compiles but when i execute its says " SEGMENTATION FAULT, CORE DROPED". and please am confused what the value of &positions will be in add_points.    thanks once again

Comment: The code didn't compile cleanly; it was broken (sorry!).  I've fixed it, and removed the 'caveat emptor' signs since I'm pretty sure it is OK now.

Comment: thanks...its working now though i still used the first code but now am using malloc.... but its till the same i cant get the different values of x and y into an equation. it keeps using same x and y